# Function that returns a list of 6-element or 3-element tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that compare the 3 elements of each `3-tuple` of two `list` with different sizes. Specifically, I want to write a function `match` as follows:

```
list1 = ['a','b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']; #just an example of a list1
list2 = ['c','a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a']; #just an example of a list2

def match(list1, list2, storage = []):
    for i in range(0, len(list1), 3):
       for j in range(0, len(list2), 3):
       #matching rule
          if (list1[i] == list2[j+1] and list1[i] == list2[j+2]) or (list1[i] == list2[j+1] and (list1[i] == list1[i+1] or list1[i] == list1[i+2])) or (list1[i] == list1[i+2] or (list1[i] == list1[i+1]) and (list2[j] == list2[j+1] or list2[j] == list2[j+2])) or (list2[j] == list1[i+1] and list2[j] == list1[i+2]):
             storage.append([list1[i], list1[i+1], list1[i+2], list2[j], list2[j+1], list2[j+2]])
         else: storage.append([list1[i], list1[i+1], list1[i+2]])
    return storage; #outside of the outer 'for' loop - obtain a list of all 6-element and/or 3-element tuples
```

Now after getting all the pairs of 3-tuples (e.g. 1 element of the list `storage` is of the form `['a','b', 'a','c','a', 'a']`),  I want to get the indices of **all** elements in `storage` that contains `['a', 'b', 'a']` as a portion of a 6-element list (e.g. `['a','b', 'a','c','a', 'a']`)  or 3-element list (e.g. `['a','b', 'a']`) - the only 2 types of list in `storage`.

**Question.** Can anyone please help me with verifying if my function is correct, and then the part on finding indices? I would greatly appreciate any inputs.

Comment: I would definitly use strings instead of lists then use " for i in range(len(str1)-3): if str1[i:i+3] in str2: "

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind that super-long `if` condition?

Comment: I just want to point out that having this `storage = []` in your function definition is a bad idea.

Comment: @Axe319 If he removes it, he wil just gets errors at 'storage.append'. And he may pass an existing list as param in his real code. So defaut value is pertinent here. Why is it a bad idea for you ?

Comment: @MartialP It's a bad idea because mutable defaults will not work the way you expect them to. If you leave it empty it will not create an empty list every time you execute the function. It will keep appending to the initial one. A common practice is to use `storage=None` and then use `storage = storage if storage is not None else []` to give yourself an empty list if you don't set the default. You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @Axe319: thank you very much for pointing that out. I sincerely appreciate your help. I have a follow-up question though: if I declare 
`def match(list1, list2, storage = None): 
      if storage is not None: 
          storage = [];
          storage.append([argument here])....
    return storage 
`
Does the `storage` change each time I call the `match` function (i.e, if i call the `match` function 10 times, I would get `10` different lists?). And is this the right way to execute function `match`: `match([input list1], [input list2], storage1)`?

Comment: If you don't plan on passing anything in to `storage` there's no need to have it in your arguments. If you do have it in and want to optionally pass in a list I would set it to `None` in your args. Other than that everything looks good and yes, you would have a fresh list every time you execute it. Not setting it to anything AND having it in your args makes it a required argument.

Comment: @Aex319: How do I declare a list of a list though, so that I only need to refer to the index of a big list? For example, `list[1]` would contain *every* matching of Type 1, `list[2]` would contain "every" matching of Type 2, and so on. Also, can you please help with the indexing question in my OP?

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you:

```
str1 = "abaacbabaacbabca" #...
l = []
l.append("caacaa")
l.append("ghijhg") # any 6 letter long string
l.append("acbaca")
for str2 in l:
    if any(str1[i:i+3] in str2 for i in range(len(str1)-3)):
        print(str2)
```

it returns (print):

```
caacaa
acbaca
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why is it better to store the characters as strings rather than individual elements in a `list`?

Comment: Also your code did not return the positions of the str that was contained. Can you see if you can help with that? The use of `any` is great though.

Comment: @user177196 1st : because it is way simple to understand and it is want strings are made for. I'll probably use list again if I edit just in case you used letters only to make the question straightforward, because if you really work with list of letters, just make them strings. 2nd : Does the any() condition is it what your if "rule" was trying to achieve ?  3rd : your's didn't either, where do you want indexes to be saved ? You may explain exactly what do you want your result (return) to be so we can give you the answer you need.

Comment: I just post a new question here to explain what I want. Can you please help? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773986/list-of-indices-of-tuples-of-tuples-that-contain-certain-tuples