# List of indices of tuples of tuples that contain certain tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list `list1` of 3 sublists of tuples like

```
[[(['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'O']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'A', 'O']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'O'])],
 [(['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'A', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'A'])],
 [['A', 'B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'O']],
 [['A', 'B', 'B']],
 [['B', 'A', 'A']]]
```

Assume `list2 = ['A', 'B', 'A'].` My goal is to obtain **a list of indices** of any pairs of tuples (or a singleton set of tuple) in `list1` that contain the tuple `list2`. I tried to use the `enumerate` function as follows but the result is not correct

```
print([i for i, j in enumerate(bigset) if ['A', 'B', 'A'] in j[0] or 
       ['A', 'B', 'A'] == j[0] or [['A', 'B', 'A']] in j[0]])
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem? I'm quite stuck due to the mismatch in the different sizes of tuples of tuples appearing in `list1`.

Another question I have is: I want to find the **total number of 3-element lists** in `list1`. So if I do it by hand, the answer is `22`. But how to do it in code? I guess we need to use two `for` loops?

**Expected Output** For `list1` above with the given `list2`, we would get the list of indices containing `list2` is `[0,1,5,6,7,9,10]`.

Comment: You have a list of five lists, the inner lists sometimes containing tuples, containing lists. Please share the exact output you want for `list1`.

Comment: There are no "tuples of tuples" in the posted code.  What you have is mostly lists with a few tuples here and there.  It's almost impossible to read as posted.  Why not split up the long line?

Comment: It's very unorganized. You better change it to a more friendly format (eg a list of lists of tuples) and review what you want to achieve

Comment: @timgeb: I showed the exact output I want for `list1.` Can you please help? The reason I have `tuples` is because I use the function `list(itertools.product())` to create those pairs.

Comment: @TomKarzes: please treat each pair of tuple as an element within the big list. I only care about obtaining the list of positions of those pairs  that contains the given tuple in `list2.` Is it clearer to you now?

Comment: @user177196 `list1` doesn't contain a tuple. It contains three strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I fixed my wording. But can you please help solve the main problem? The meaning of the OP still stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here you go

This use recursion because we don't know the depth of your `list1` SO the index will be counted like this :

```
0,1
2,3,4,
6,7
8,
9,10,11,12
```

etc... (The same order you have by writing it in 1 row)

Here the result will be :

```
[0, 2, 8, 10, 12, 16, 18]
```

Now the code

```
def foo(l,ref):
    global s
    global indexes
    for items in l:  #if it's an element of 3 letters
        if len(items)== 3 and len(items[0])==1:
            if items == ref: 
                indexes.append(s) #save his index if it match the ref
            s+= 1  #next index
        else: #We need to go deeper
            foo(items,ref)
    return(s)
          
        
list1 = [[(['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'O']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'A', 'O']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'O', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'O'])],
 [(['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'O'], ['B', 'A', 'A']),
  (['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'A', 'A'])],
 [['A', 'B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'O']],
 [['A', 'B', 'B']],
 [['B', 'A', 'A']]]

list2 = ['A', 'B', 'A']
indexes = []
s=0
count= foo(list1,list2)
print(indexes)
```

`s` is the index we are working on
`count` is the total amount of element (22).
`Indexes` is the list of index you want.

This work even if you make a `list3 = [list1,list1,[list1,[list1],list1]]` , you may want to try it.

Best luck to end your script now.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work for your implementation if we sort out your list1 into a more friendly format first? If so, you could do that in a pretty simple way:

Go through each element of list1, if the element is itself a big list of tuples, then we want to unpack further. If the element is a tuple (so the first element of that tuple is a list), or it is itself one of your 3-element lists, then we just want to append that as it is.

```
nice_list = []
for i in list1:
    if type(i[0]) == str or type(i[0]) == list:
        # i.e. i is one of your 3-element lists, or a tuple of lists
        nice_list.append(i)
    else:
        #If i is still a big list of other tuples, we want to unpack further
        for j in i:
            nice_list.append(j)
```

Then you could search for the indices much easier:

```
for i, idx in zip(nice_list, range(len(nice_list))): 
    if ['A', 'B', 'A'] in i: 
        print(idx) #Or append them to a list, whatever you wanted to do
```

For a not-particularly-elegant solution to your question about finding how many 3-element lists there are, yes you could use a for loop:

```
no_of_lists = 0
for n in nice_list:
    if type(n) == tuple:
        no_of_lists += len(n)
    elif type(n) == list and type(n[0]) == list:
        # if it is a list of lists
        no_of_lists += len(n)
    elif type(n) == list and type(n[0]) == str:
        #if it is a 3-element list
        no_of_lists_lists += 1
print('Number of 3-element lists contained:', no_of_lists)
```

Edit: to answer the question you asked in the comments about how the `for n in nice_list` part works, this just iterates through each element of the list. To explore this, try writing some code to print out `nice_list[0]`, `nice_list[1]` etc, or a for loop which prints out each `n` so you can see what that looks like. For example, you could do:

```
for n in nice_list:
    print(n)
```

to understand how that's working.

Comment: can you please clarify on the `If` condition? What do `str` and `list` in this case mean?

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This is awesome! I tried your code on finding how many 3-element lists are there, and apparently the result is 21. rather than 22. I think it might not count element of type either `[['A', 'B', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'O']]` or `[['A', 'B', 'B']]`

Comment: Ah sorry about that, when I did it first time it returned 22 as expected! Let me just go in and fix that

Comment: another added question though. If I want to define a variable b[i] such that b[1] = 2 if the first tuple elements of the first sublist is 2 (and b[1]=1 otherwise), b[2] = 2 if the second tuple elements of the first sublist is 2, and so on, then I would have the expected output from `list1` as `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1].` Can you help me accomplish this goal?

Comment: Also, how do I get the total number of 1& 2-element tuples (or 2-element list of list)? For example, in `list1`, we have `12` of them.

Comment: That's quite simple, just `b = [len(i) for i in nice_list] ` for your first question, and then `len(b)` for your second. Also, please remember to up-vote / mark answers as correct if they help you, it really helps those of us who are relatively new!

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help! I upvoted your answers now. I have a quick question: so for lists of lists of tuples, every time we run the `for` loop like `for i in nice_list`, the `i` here is automatically understood by Python to go by index of the large tuples only? For example, if we have sets like `L = [[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'A')]]`, how does the result change due to that `for i in nice_list` loop?

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for that.I've added to my answer above to answer your question about the for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly unconventional approach, due to unknown depth, and/or lack of known array flattening operation - I would try with regex:

```py
import re

def getPos(el, arr):
    el=re.escape(str(el))
    el=f"(\({el})|({el}\))"
    i=0
    for s in re.finditer(r"\([^\)]+\)", str(arr)):
        if(re.match(el,s.group(0))):
            yield i
        i+=1
```

Which yields:

```py
>>> print(list(getPos(list2, list1)))

[0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

(Which I believe is the actual result you want).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Did you use Python 3? I tried your code, but i got the error `el=f"(\({el})|({el}\))"
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Yes, python3 - for earlier versions just do : `el="(\({0})|({0}\))".format(el)`